# Symfony Webpack not able to build due to missing modules when installing npm package

Tags: javascript, symfony, npm, webpack

I was trying to install the [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) package into a new symfony 6.0 project with webpack. I'm able to install it, but as soon as I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 7 errors                                             

Module build failed: Module not found:
"./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js" contains a reference to the file "fs".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js" contains a reference to the file "child_process".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js" contains a reference to the file "fs".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js" contains a reference to the file "fs".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js" contains a reference to the file "net".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js" contains a reference to the file "tls".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./node_modules/node-forge/lib/random.js" contains a reference to the file "jquery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .addPlugin(new NodePolyfillPlugin())
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Its pretty basic, but I'm not able to get it going. Any ideas?

Comment: Can I see your app.js please @Codekx ?

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz Thanks for your comment. There's nothing much in it, just `import './styles/app.css';`, `import './bootstrap;` and the package, which causes the issues. In this case `const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');`

Comment: Did u try npm audit fix ?

Comment: `npm install  google-spreadsheet` and `npm audit fix` and to finish you can rerun `npm install`

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz Sadly, this does not fix the issue.

Comment: @Codekx Cheat... :/ Have you try also to delete the `node_modules` folder before restart the `npm install` command ?

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz Were you able te fix it? I'm in a similar situation

Comment: @Graph sorry but it wasn't my problem, I was trying to solve it for Jan instead